# Display something based off a PHP session

Tags: php, web

I need some help with displaying a success message on my website.

Whats supposed to happen:
You submit a form, it then sends it to my email ( all works flawlessly ) then it takes you to my homepage and displays this

```
[php]
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
</script>

<style> 
#panel,#flip
{
padding:2px;
text-align:center;
background-color:#00BFFF;
border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
#panel
{
padding:20px;
display:none;
}
</style>
<body>

<div id="flip"><b>Submitted!</b> (Click for more)</div>
<div id="panel">Your form has been submitted. If your form required being contacted, you will be contacted ASAP.</div>
</body>
</html>
[/php]
```

The problem is, I need that ^ to only appear when you submit a form. As of now, it appears even if you don't submit a form.

With some help of some people, I was informed to use PHP sessions to display it only when you click the submit button.

After compiling both my code, with theirs we got the code below. The "Home Page:" represents where the submit button will take you, along with where it displays the "success!" form. The "Submit form page:" is the page in which the session is started. Someone please tell me what is wrong here.

Home Page:

```
[php]
<!-- PHP session beginning -->
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION["sent"])) {
 // Start
?>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
</script>

<style> 
#panel,#flip
{
padding:2px;
text-align:center;
background-color:#00BFFF;
border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
#panel
{
padding:20px;
display:none;
}
</style>
<body>

<div id="flip"><b>Submitted!</b> (Click for more)</div>
<div id="panel">Your form has been submitted. If your form required being contacted, you will be   

contacted ASAP.</div>

</body>
</html>
<?php
session_start();
// terminate the session
session_destroy();
?>
<!-- PHP Session end. Displays sent information only when sent -->[/php]
```

Contact submit page:

```
[php]
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["sent"] = true;  // or any value really
?> 
[/php]
```

I really, really appreciate you reading this. You can ignore the [php] brackets,

Contact form (Per request)

```
    <!--Form start-->
                        <form name="htmlform" method="post" action="html_form_send.php">
<table width="450px">
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="first_name">Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="30" size="20">
 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td valign="top"">
  <label for="last_name">Username *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="30" size="20">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="email">Skype Username *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="30" size="20">
 </td>

</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="telephone">Previous Staff Rank</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="20">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="comments">Why should we hire you? *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="3"></textarea>
 </td>

</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form><br><br><br>
<!--Form end-->
```

The "html_form_send" is the code that handles this, which is where I would start the PHP session.

Comment: You actually are starting the session twice.

Comment: You never closed your `if` statement.

Comment: Briosheje, I will fix that, but I'm positive it isn't the cause to it being displayd no matter what.

Comment: Jeremiah, where did I not close it? Is that the cause to this? If so, could you possibly tell me which section it is in ( Home page, Contact form page) and also expand on it, possibly show me the fixed code?

Comment: Can you post what your form looks like?

Comment: When you post code here (or debug it) try to clear the not esencials parts, like the `stailing`, text `divs`, etc. It makes the whole thing  easier to spot the poroblems

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are initializing de session before **anything**. This is wrong:

```
<!-- PHP session beginning -->
<?php
session_start();
```

It must be:

```
<?php
session_start();
```

Remove even a blank space (if any) between `<?php` and `session_start();`. For example, this:

```
<?php session_start();
```

wouldn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

file with form:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
  //sent e-mail etc.
  $_SESSION['success_message'] = 'Sent!';
}
?>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="email">
 ...
</form>
```

homepage:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
... your content
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['success_message'])): ?>
 <p>Message was sent</p>
 <?php unset($_SESSION['success_message']; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I don't understand, or the question was too confusing. I already have a form, once the button is hit, it submits it. I then am trying to run a small section of code that "gives access" to display a success message on my home page. All this did was cause another text input to appear once the button was hit.

Comment: My answer was just an example how you can do it - basic logic is to call start_session() at the beginning of both scripts. Save any value into session right after sending e-mail and redirect after that. Than remove message from session once it's displayed.

Comment: Is it session_start() or start_session()?                             Basically, I'm trying to figure out why the "success" message is not staying hidden, I can simply visit the website from a link, and it's there. No matter if you send a form or not.